# How to design result according students

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relation

This is my first post. I am in a trouble in my laravel project
Here is my data table.
[image]

I have student Id like 1,2,3. every students have multiple results followed by courses.
I need to arrange them like that
[image]

I tried groupby and got this result
[image]

Is there any possible way to arrange them according to students.
Thank You

code: controller:

```
public function notification()
{
    $auth_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $teacher = Teacher::where('user_id', $auth_id)->first();
    $teacher_id = ($teacher->id);
    $batch = Batch::where('teacher_id', $teacher_id)->first();

    $courses = AssignCourses::with('course')
        ->where('semester_id', $batch->semester_id)
        ->get();

    $current_semester_results = Result::with(['student', 'course'])
        ->where('semester_id', $batch->semester_id)
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('student.id');

    $batch_students = Student::with('result')
        ->where('semester_id', $batch->semester_id)
        ->get();

    return view('users.teacher.my_batch.notification', compact(['current_semester_results', 'courses', 'batch_students']));
}
```

Comment: Please can you add  the code you're using with the group by (copy and paste not screenshot).

Comment: I have added the code of controller.

Comment: I am not sure is groupby is actually needed in this purpose.

Comment: Why don't you just use `$batch_students` considering you're loading their results relationship anyway?

Comment: Yes I can but the courses are dynamic and each students has various course. In frontend the course 
      @foreach($courses as $course)
                            <th>
                                {{ $course->course->course_code }}

                            </th>
                            @endforeach
I can get the dynamic courses but cannot arrange the result

Comment: @foreach($batch_students as $batch_student)
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{$i++}} </td>
                            <td>{{ $batch_student->registration_number }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $batch_student->roll_number }}</td>
                                
                  
                            @foreach($current_semester_results as $result)
<td>
    {{ $result->result->l_grade }}
</td>

  
                        </tr>

Comment: Its giving me an error as [result] not found in collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `$batch_students` and apply any aggregations on your PHP code, it is easier to do it.

```php
$batch_students = Student::with('result')
    ->where('semester_id', $batch->semester_id)
    ->get();

$batch_students_grouped = $batch_students->groupBy('result.student_id');
```

**Note:** I could not test since I don't have the tables, so you might need to change the `student_id` nest/access index in the last line of code.

you can print out your `$batch_students_grouped->all()` and see how you should iterate your data and show it in frontend.

Comment: in    dd($batch_students_grouped); Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1382 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1407 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        0 => App\Models\Student {#1394 ▶}
        1 => App\Models\Student {#1404 ▶}
        2 => App\Models\Student {#1395 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: in frontend 
@foreach($batch_students as $batch_student)
                        <tr data-widget="expandable-table" aria-expanded="false">
                            <td> {{$i++}} </td>
                            <td>{{ $batch_student->registration_number }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $batch_student->roll_number }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $batch_student->firstname }}</td>

its fetching the student details but how can I show the courses marks. as courses marks are dynamic

Comment: @foreach($courses as $course)
                            <th>
                                {{ $course->course->course_code }}

                            </th>
                            @endforeach

This is the course table heading.

Comment: @joydhar can you run `dd($batch_students_grouped->toArray());` and give the result, cause this is messy to understand, sorry :'(

Comment: Yes Its worked. I have used a count variable in frontend. All are good as expected. Thank you so much.

Comment: @joydhar if this answer helped you to solve problem then kindly mark answer as accepted .

Comment: @JohnLobo Kids these days don't listen :))